# Confusing TypeScript in `mui-x` DataGrid `useGridApiRef()`

Tags: typescript, material-ui, typescript-typings, react-typescript

Can someone explain this syntax from [mui/mui-x](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/blob/be9053a181686ecf8e89f6c2b5d0ab405b6466e5/packages/grid/x-data-grid-pro/src/hooks/utils/useGridApiRef.ts#L5-L7) to me?

```js
export declare const useGridApiRef: <Api extends GridApiCommon = GridApiPro>() => React.MutableRefObject<Api>;
```

I read it as …
export a declared type that is of type `<Api extends GridApiCommon = GridApiPro>` but is actually a callable function that returns mutable reference to something that is typed 
¯_(ツ)_/¯  … seriously.

I’m less so concerned about what precisely the thing actually does, and more so confused by what this syntax is declaring. Admittedly, I'm green-ish to TS, but been in CS and dev for years, so not a noob ask.

Answer (score 0):

This function declaration would be the same as the function below:

```js
export declare function useGridApiRef<Api extends GridApiCommon = GridApiPro>() {
  return React.MutableRefObject<Api>;
}
```

It's declaring a generic function with one type-name that defaults to `GridApiPro` but with an arrow function type definition instead.

To declare an arrow function type as generic just add the type-names before the parameters like so:

```js
export declare const functionName: <T>() => {
  ...
};
```